# How the below python code's time complexity is calculated as 0(n log n)?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I was understanding how Big O calculation works, after watching few videos when I started practicing few problems, I came to this code , where I thing the code time complexity is O(n^2) because outer loop will run O(n) and inner loop will also run O(n). Because inner loop has to iterate through all the list to find the unique name.
But the blog explains it as O(n log n), How?

```
def list_unique_names(phonebook):
    unique_names = []
    for name, phonenumber in phonebook:             # 1
        first_name, last_name = name.split(" ", 1)
        for unique in unique_names:                 # 2
            if unique == first_name:
                break
        else:
            unique_names.append(first_name)
    return len(unique_names)

phonebook = [
    ("John Doe", "555-555-5555"),
    ("Albert Einstein", "212-555-5555"),
    ("John Murphey", "202-555-5555"),
    ("Albert Rutherford", "647-555-5555"),
    ("Elaine Bodian", "301-555-5555"),
]
```

I am expecting the complexity as O(n^2) but blog owner says its O(n log n).

Comment: @khelwood I have fixed it , thanks. It was copy paste mistake

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Sorry I did not get your answer.

Comment: I did not understand for who this question was not clear and does not shows research was not done before posting this, rather doing this negative things please try to answer the question so that we can get something out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the code you posted runs in `O(n^2)`.

With the use of a `set`, you can do the same operation in `amortized O(n)`:

```
def list_unique_names(phonebook):
    unique_names = set()
    for name, phonenumber in phonebook:
        first_name, _ = name.split(" ", 1)
        unique_names.add(first_name)
    return len(unique_names)
```

Comment: Thanks , I was aware of using set here, I was only confused with the time complexity analysis done by blog author i.e. O(n log n). Thanks for clarifying my doubt.